# ur_gazebo: changed controller configuration does not work

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello I'm using ros-melodic and I'm having trouble with controlling ur5 manipulator with gazebo

I downloaded ur_gazebo package from https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot.git
Planning and execution with the moveit works well.

What I trying to do is to execute position control of each joint from the optimization result.

So, I modified the source code to watch how it works.

What I wanted is to control **shoulder_pan_joint** by publishing data through rostopic

I changed **ur5.launch**, and **arm_controller_ur5.yaml** like below

ur5.launch

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="limited" default="false"  doc="If true, limits joint range [-PI, PI] on all joints." />
  <arg name="paused" default="false" doc="Starts gazebo in paused mode" />
  <arg name="gui" default="true" doc="Starts gazebo gui" />
  
  <!-- startup simulated world -->
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/empty.world"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="$(arg paused)"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="$(arg gui)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- send robot urdf to param server -->
  <include file="$(find ur_description)/launch/ur5_upload.launch">
    <arg name="limited" value="$(arg limited)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
  <node name="spawn_gazebo_model" pkg="gazebo_ros" type="spawn_model" args="-urdf -param robot_description -model robot -z 0.1" respawn="false" output="screen" />

  <include file="$(find ur_gazebo)/launch/controller_utils.launch"/>

  <!-- start this controller -->
  <rosparam file="$(find ur_gazebo)/controller/arm_controller_ur5.yaml" command="load"/>
  <node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>

  <!-- load other controllers -->
  <node name="ros_control_controller_manager" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" respawn="false" output="screen" args="load joint_group_position_controller" />


  <node name="simple_controller" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" respawn="false" output="screen" args="load prac" />


</launch>
```

arm_controller.yaml

```
prac:
  type: position_controllers/JointPositionController
  joint: shoulder_pan_joint
  pid:
    p: 100.0
    d: 10.0


arm_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointTrajectoryController
  joints:
     - shoulder_pan_joint
     - shoulder_lift_joint
     - elbow_joint
     - wrist_1_joint
     - wrist_2_joint
     - wrist_3_joint
  constraints:
      goal_time: 0.6
      stopped_velocity_tolerance: 0.05
      shoulder_pan_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
      shoulder_lift_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
      elbow_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
      wrist_1_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
      wrist_2_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
      wrist_3_joint: {trajectory: 0.1, goal: 0.1}
  stop_trajectory_duration: 0.5
  state_publish_rate:  25
  action_monitor_rate: 10
joint_group_position_controller:
  type: position_controllers/JointGroupPositionController
  joints:
     - shoulder_pan_joint
     - shoulder_lift_joint
     - elbow_joint
     - wrist_1_joint
     - wrist_2_joint
     - wrist_3_joint
```

In ur5.launch I added node named simple controller, and in yaml file I added the controller desctription

 Then, I run the launch file

```
roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch
```

and published desired position by

```
rostopic pub /prac/command std_msgs/Float64 "data: 0.5"
```

However, the robot doesn't seem to move.

 Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377279/ur_gazebo:-changed-controller-configuration-does-not-work/) by [ilkwon](https://answers.ros.org/users/73877/ilkwon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-04-29

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ilkwon](https://answers.ros.org/users/73877/ilkwon/) on 2021-04-30**:
What I think is the cause of this problem is when I do the roslaunch ur_gazebo ur5.launch, I get these messages

```
Loaded 'prac'
Loaded 'joint_group_position_controller'
Loaded 'joint_state_controller'
Started ['joint_state_controller'] successfully
Loaded 'arm_controller'
Started ['arm_controller'] successfully
```

It seems to prac(the single joint controller I added) is just loaded and not started.

How can I deal with this problem?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-04-30**:
This doesn't seem like a problem with `ur_gazebo`, but with how you changed the provided files and the way you interact with the controllers.

The title should reflect that.

---

Edit: I've updated the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have this in the `.launch` file you edited:

> ```
> <!-- start this controller -->
> ```

```
<rosparam file="$(find ur_gazebo)/controller/arm_controller_ur5.yaml" command="load"/>
<node name="arm_controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" args="spawn arm_controller" respawn="false" output="screen"/>
```

> 

```
<!-- load other controllers -->
<node name="ros_control_controller_manager" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" respawn="false" output="screen" args="load joint_group_position_controller" />
```

> 

```
<node name="simple_controller" pkg="controller_manager" type="controller_manager" respawn="false" output="screen" args="load prac" />
```

The `simple_controller` node (which is essentially a `controller_manager`) only `load`s the controller settings with the name `prac`.

You don't actually *start* the controller. For that, you'd need to run the `controller_manager` with the `spawn` argument.

Note: with the current `.launch` file, the `arm_controller` is `spawn`ed.

You cannot start two controllers for the same joint (*resource* really) at the same time. That would lead to conflicts, and is specifically prohibited.

You'll have to stop the running controller and then start your `prac` controller. You could either do that in separate steps, or use the [switch_controller service](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager#Services).

Note also: because your `prac` controller controls only a single joint, I expect the rest of the robot to flail around in Gazebo.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-04-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ilkwon](https://answers.ros.org/users/73877/ilkwon/) on 2021-05-01**:
Oh....
This worked thanks!,!